# Gradle shared library project

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to migrate from Maven to Gradle (for our Android projects)...

We have multiple apk projects and a single shared aar library project.  Each of the projects are independent, and have their own release, version numbers, and git repo.

Here is our setup:

A - Project1

B - Project2

C - Project3

L - Common Library Project

-

A depends on L

B depends on L

C depends on L

When developing with Maven, when building L, it would place the built artifact in the Maven local cache, then when building B it would use L from the local cache (with the latest developer changes to L).  It seems that Gradle does not use a shared local cache.

How do I setup these projects in Gradle so that a developer can build B and L on a developer machine (so that changes the developer makes in L will show up in B)?

I also would like to be able to place the L project anywhere on the local machine (I would like to keep the projects as independent as possible).

Answer (score 0):

Declare a repository with a `file://` URL, and use it to exchange artifacts between the builds. You can also use `mavenLocal()`, but it will hurt reproducibility of your builds, and there are known issues with it.